# Xcode does not show all my teams

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Here is what I see at Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts:
[image]

Here is what I see at developer.apple.com -> Certificates, Identifiers & ProfilesWill:
[image]

However, according to iTunesConnect I am on another team:
[image]

---

How I got into this situation:

- I have previously used my account to upload and release software to iTunesConnect
- The admin for Kim Rubin has not made any changes to my access level in the meantime
- I have purchased a new MacBook (now regretting) and allowed Xcode to create a new certificate (always clicking whatever the default Xcode response was)

---

**Please explain why Xcode does not recognize my other team membership.**

Downstream this is also causing other problems. (Specifically, I cannot upload to iTC because Xcode is trying to sign with the wrong team.) But right now I am only asking about the root cause above.

Comment: There is a difference between your role in itunes connect and on the developer account.  I suspect you have the itunes connect role, but your developer account is not an appropriate role for creating signing assets.  It probably worked on your old Mac because you were given the signing identity files at some point (cert, key and profile) and the project was set up to use those.  On the new mac, you didn't have those, and when you clicked "Fix Issues", Xcode used the only developer account with permissions to create signing identity assets, which seems to be your personal account.

Comment: Developer program roles: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/ vs. iTunes Connect roles: https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Users%20and%20Roles_Overview

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get more information in my comments, but without more information, I can explain what I think is happening.  You state that your access hasn't changed, but you previously used the account to upload and submit the app through iTunes Connect.  You never mention that you used your account to actually build and sign the application that you submitted.  I'm guessing you either did not, or if you did it was using manual signing and the old Mac had the iOS distribution code signing identity on it.

It appears you have been granted an [iTunes Connect role](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Users%20and%20Roles_Overview), but not [Apple Developer role](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/). In order to have the team show up in Xcode and allow for things like creation of a certificate / profile, you need to be at least an Admin role on the developer account.  When you clicked "Fixed issue" in Xcode, because you only had your personal dev account available, Xcode tried to create a cert and profile on your new account.  That will result in a build that was improperly signed, as you need it to be signed with the correct account's certificate and profile.

You can either have the owner of the account add you as a development team admin, or you can have someone on the team send you the iOS distribution certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: This isn't the answer — I'm listed as the Admin on multiple accounts and only one appears.

Answer (score 0):

In case of my team member who's role was "Customer Support", changing the role to "Developer" was not enough. The solution was to delete his account and recreate it with "Developer" role in Itunes Connect, and only after accepting new invitation the team was showing up in Xcode.